# How to save Selected tab after postback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to save the selected tab after postback.

For example, I select Tab login2 that contains a Button which causes a postback on click. After the postback occurs, Tab login1 regains the focus and I have to manually select Tab login2.

HTML code:

```
<div class="login-form">
    <ul class="login-tabs">
        <li>
            <a href="#login1" class="active">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#login2">2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="login1" class="form-action show">
        login1
    </div>
    <div id="login2" class="form-action hide">
        login2
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.login-tabs').on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
    alert(SelectedTab);
    e.preventDefault();
    var $tab = $(this),
    href = $tab.attr('href');

    SelectedTab = 2;
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $tab.addClass('active');

    $('.show')
        .removeClass('show')
        .addClass('hide')
        .hide();

    $(href)
        .removeClass('hide')
        .addClass('show')
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(550);
});
```

select the last selected tab.

Comment: You can use `localStorage` to set the state and read it after the postback